# Why is the solution to the Blasius boundary layer problem self-similar?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

In every course or textbook that I encountered so far, the authors transform the Navier-Stokes equations of the Blasius boundary layer problem into the Blasius ODE. The problem with many of those texts is that they claim that the solution is self-similar and give very weak justifications, or none at all and that really bothers me as I'm trying to understand rigorously why such a transformation is possible.

Does anyone know of references to look at for a rigorous proof of the above claim, or at least an experience showing that the plot of $\frac{u}{U_{\infty}}$ vs $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}$ doesn't change when changing $x$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The [wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius_boundary_layer) page on Blasius boundary layers is a useful and thorough resource in this case.

Blasius boundary layers arise in steady, laminar 2D flow over a semi-infinite plate oriented parallel to the flow. In this scenario, the Navier-Stokes equations are particularly simple and amount to a leading-order balance between inertia and viscous forces. The similarity solutions are derived from scaling arguments of these equations. It's not worth me repeating the derivation of the ode as the [wiki page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius_boundary_layer) is very thorough.

Comment: Actually the scaling argument only gives you an idea about the order of magnitude of the boundary layer thickness and has nothing to do with $\frac{u}{U_{\infty}}$ depending only on the Prandtl variable $\eta$. Wikipedia is among those sources that give no proof that the problem can in fact be expressed using only the reduced coordinate $\eta$. It seems to me that most just find it covenient, and also a little bit intuitive, and as such impose such a form.

Comment: @B.S. Yes, the scaling arguments given you an order of magnitude for the boundary layer thickness, but then you use this as a length scale to construct the similarity variable, $\eta$.  Once we find a similarity variable, we can construct a similarity solution for the velocity, $u(x,y) = U_{\infty} f(\eta)$ which, of course, depends only on $\eta \sim y/\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Yes I understand the intuition behind the construction of the similarity variable, but still, it is not a proof that $u$ can in fact be written as a function of $\eta$ only. At the moment one can only write $u (x,y)=F(\eta,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The  self  similarity  condition  is  applied  when  deriving  the  Blasius  equation,  implying  that the  streamwise  velocity  $u(x,  y)$  across  a  boundary  layer  is  a  function  of  the  derivative of  $f(\eta)$  scaled  by  the  flow  $U$  as  follows $$u(x,  y)  =  Uf'(\eta)$$  The  self-similar  streamwise  profile  derives  from  the  following stream  function.  $$\psi(x,y)  =(U\nu  x)^{\frac{1}{2}}f(\eta)$$  To  see  this  clearly,  we differentiate  the  streamfunction  with  respect  to  $x$,  finding  the  $x$  component  of  the  velocity. $$u(x,y)  =  \frac{\partial  \psi}{\partial  y}  =  U(U\nu  x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\,\,f'(\eta)\frac{d\eta}{dy}  =  U(U \nu  x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\,\,f'(\eta)\bigg(\frac{U}{\nu  x}\bigg)^\frac{1}{2}$$  Which  simplifies  to  the desired equation.

Answer (score -1):

If there are no solutions of that form you wont find any.

Comment: Another addition to my collection of weird downvotes!